# jQuery. Как написать функцию?

Tags: jquery

Сейчас у меня такой код:

```
var f = $(".sl1 .sm_imgs a").first().attr("href");
$(".sl1 .sl_img img").attr("src", f);

$(".sl1 .sm_imgs a").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".sl1 .sl_img img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Основная составляющая - .sl1. Она будет меняться (.sl1, .sl2 и т.д.). Чтобы не писать одно и то же все время я хочу написать функцию, что бы потом одной строкой выполнить весь тот код. Но я никак не могу этого сделать. На выходе, по идее должно получиться типа такого:

```
$(".sl1").myfn();
$(".sl2").myfn();
```

Но что то не получается. Не понимаю, где this использовать или еще чего.. Помогите плиз

Comment: Что получилось прям как Вы хотите $(".sl1").myfn(), нужно будет написать jQuery-плагин. В любом случае, я бы Вам рекомендовал использовать кэширование наборов, например var $s1 = $(".sl1"); Это сэкономит вам и код и облегчит понимание.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поскольку, в Sizzle (CSS Selector Engine) будет варьироватся только один класс для селекции (исходя из вопроса), то лучше будет так

```
$(function(){

  $.myfn = function(slClass){
    var f = $(slClass + ".sm_imgs a").first().attr("href");
    $(slClass + " .sl_img img").attr("src", f);

    $(slClass + " .sm_imgs a").click(function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       $(slClass + " .sl_img img").attr("src", $(this).attr("href"));
    });
  };

  // Использование:
  $.myfn(".sl1");
  $.myfn(".sl2");

});
```

Для того чтобы было так `$(".sl1").myfn();` - нужно расширить Jquery обьект добавлением вышеуказанного метода по аналогии предыдущим, вот так:

```
(function($){

   $.fn.myfunc = function(...){...} //this - будет значение селектора

})(Jquery);
```

Но это нужно когда новый метод может быть применён глобально относительно дерева DOM - в особенности для новых элементов с сервера, которые обрабатываются так:

```
$(document).on("event", "selector", function(e){
  ...
})
```

Имею ввиду, что этот метод будет привязан к обработчикам всех элементов (даже к тем что никогда не будут использоватся), что означает утечку памяти. Лучше воспользуйтесь первым вариантом, т.к он больше Вам подходит.